# Given 4 points, how to crop a quadrilateral from an image in pytorch/torchvision?

Tags: python, image, pytorch, torchvision

Problem is pretty straightforward -

I want to crop a quadrilateral from an image in pytorch/torchvision. Given, I have four coordinates of the corners of this quadrilateral.

Please note that these four points confine a quadrilateral within themselves which may or may not be a rectangle. So please refrain from suggesting answers involving slicing of the image.

Please comment if I have missed any relevant detail.

Comment: can you update  what you have treid so far ?

Comment: I went thru their documentation - https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torchvision/transforms.html in vain, either I missed something or whatever I am asking is not implemented.

Comment: You showed no details of any code you tried / found nor what your _research_ on this topic brought to light. Maybe add it to make clearer what you tried and what failed / why it failed. A small picture of a "quadrilateral" on an image might be a valid use of a picture in your post.

Comment: @PatrickArtner thank you for the comment. I will update it once the 'quadrilateral image' is ready.

Comment: Generally speaking, painting the quadlit (assuming its in the same coords then your image) on a new image, setting all outside points to some value and using it as mask over your original image would work in PIL - for a PIL example see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52455886/transparency-not-working-consistently-while-saving-gifs-in-pil/52455943) (it's using a font-mask over a image to get a image-background font) - might help you find smth similar in torchvision which I havent used yet.

Comment: I want to do it in torch. I cant use numpy arrays in the code as I am using torch's nn which breaks during the backward pass if all the entities dont have a dtype of torch.Tensor*

Comment: From a glance at torchvision your situation looks like this to me:  _I have a hammer and a chisel but I need fine onion slices_ - hope you can pull it off. Cheers.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180989/discussion-between-markroxor-and-patrick-artner).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting https://stackoverflow.com/a/30902423/4982729 I could extract the patch using opencv as -

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

pts = np.array([[542, 107], [562, 102], [582, 110], [598, 142], [600, 192], [601, 225], [592, 261], [572, 263], [551, 245], [526, 220], [520, 188], [518, 152], [525, 127], [524, 107]], dtype=np.int32)

mask = np.zeros((img.shape[0], img.shape[1]))

cv2.fillConvexPoly(mask, pts, 1)
mask = mask.astype(np.bool)

out = np.zeros_like(img)
out[mask] = img[mask]
```

[image]

and then I could convert the numpy array to torch's Variable manually. This seems to raise no errors even when I am forming torch's graph for neural networks.

```
    outputs = model(images)
    o = outputs.data.cpu().numpy()
    #
    # do your opencv stuff here to o
    #
    o = torch.Tensor(o).to(device)
    outputs = Variable(o, requires_grad=True)
```